# Casting in Java with hierachy of generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, nested-generics

These are my classes definition:

```
public interface Entity ...
public abstract class EntityBaseClass implements Entity  ...
public class ArticleCategory extends EntityBaseClass ...
```

And

```
public interface GenericService<T extends Entity> 
public interface ArticleCategoryService extends GenericService<ArticleCategory>
public class ArticleCategoryServiceImpl implements ArticleCategoryService
```

Why can't I do something like this:

```
GenericService<Entity> x = new ArticleCategoryServiceImpl();
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ArticleCategoryServiceImpl` implements `ArticleCategoryService` which extends `GenericService<ArticleCategory>` which is not the same as `GenericService<Entity>`.

You should look at the object being instantiated for polymorphism not the generics it uses.

You can declare x as `GenericService<ArticleCategory>` though. Which may better since `ArticleCategory>` can do as much as an `Entity` and then some.

Comment: Since ArticleCategory extends Entity, why GenericService<ArticleCategory> is not the same as GenericService<Entity> ?

Comment: Well when you have GenericService<ArticleCategory> vs GenericService<Entity> in the background java essentially compiles 2 individual classes. One that replaces all the generic references in `GenericService` with `ArticleCategory` and another that replaces all the generic reference in `GenericService` with `ArticleCategory`. So essentially you are dealing with two completely different classes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it like this, if you would have a `GenericService<Entity>`, then you would have for example, a method like this: `add(Entity entity)`, you could pass in ANY entity, even one that is not an `ArticleCategory`, those causing a exception when handled in the `ArticleCategoryServiceImpl` implementation. (Remember this implementation takes an `ArticleCategory` as an argument for the `add` method)

`ArticleCategory` is an `Entity`, but `GenericService<ArticleCategory>` is not a `GenericService<Entity>`